# Android POST connection timeout

Tags: java, android, post, httpconnection

I'm trying to do a POST connection but it's not working. The error is "connect time out".
Im sending an string and receiving another string and the post parameter is "quest".
The server is working fine. I have done tests uploading a site for POST connections, and it all working. I am thinking that the problem is on the android side 'cause it's my first time trying to do a POST connection.

Also the server side is Node.js with Express framework handling with the call on /search.

Here is the Java code:

```
public class DownloadDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> { 
    public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "POST";
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 20000;
    //public static final String charset = "UTF-8";
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 20000;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //Log.i(TAGAsync, "ON PRE EXECUTE");
        //Toast.makeText(TAGAs,"Buscando Servidor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // params[0] an string
        String stringUrl = "http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX:3000/search"; //blocked for security reasons
        String quest = "quest="+params[0]; //enter the parameter
        int responseCode = 0;
        String result;
        String inputLine;

        try{
            URL myUrl = new URL(stringUrl);

            HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
            connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

            //connection.connect();

            String urlParameters = URLEncoder.encode(quest, "UTF-8");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            dStream.flush();
            dStream.close();

            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }

            reader.close();
            streamReader.close();

            result = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            Log.i(TAGAsync, "URL: "+ stringUrl + " Error: " + e.getMessage() + " responseCode: " + responseCode);
            //Toast.makeText(TAGAs,"Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            result = null;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I was wondering if the error is on my Java code. Can someone help?

Edit:

```
05/16 21:39:03: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t -p com.bizzo.speech4beef C:\Users\Bizzo\AndroidStudioProjects\Speech4Beef\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.bizzo.speech4beef/com.bizzo.speech4beef.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 23492 on device asus-asus_x00ld-HAAXB602M664EG3
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.bizzo.speech4beef-1/lib/arm64
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.bizzo.speech4beef
V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.bizzo.speech4beef
                Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
V/BoostFramework: mAcquireFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[])
                  mReleaseFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease()
                  mAcquireTouchFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
V/BoostFramework: mIOPStart method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
                  mIOPStop method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop()
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@c812720
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@fa998d9
W/AbstractGoogleClient: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : c5b7903, Ic4cf336e0a
          Build Date                       : 02/17/17
          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.04
          Local Branch                     : 
          Remote Branch                    : 
          Remote Branch                    : 
          Reconstruct Branch               : 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@901f80d
I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/AsyncTask: URL: http://<--ComputerIP-->:3000/search Error: Connection timed out responseCode: 0
I/AsyncTask: Error to download data: main
```

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace coming from your client code ?

Comment: Switching to `Retrofit` would make your task much easier.

Comment: Yes, I know retrofit can be much easier but I'm trying to learn this way first.

Comment: I think you might be encoding your parameters wrong. Lets say "params[0] contains a string "tom" then your will be urlParameters  = "quest%3Dtom"  but what you want is probably "quest=tom". So you need to encode each part like this::  String part1 = URLEncoder.encode("quest", "UTF-8"); String part2 = URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "UTF-8");  Then String urlParameters = part1 + "=" + part2;

Comment: try to set timeout more longer such as  READ_TIMEOUT = 60000; and CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 60000;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example I just took from fully functional code, so this should work.

Just create a method to handle your request:

```
public String makeHttpRequest(Map<String, String> params){
    String result = "";
    InputStream responseStream = null;

    String logMess = "";
    long startTime;
    long stopTime;
    long elapsedTime;

    try {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()){
            if(postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }

        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        //This should be addressing some script like PHP something like search.php
        String stringUrl = "http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX:3000/search"; 
        URL myUrl = new URL(stringUrl);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));

        DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        request.write(postDataBytes);
        request.flush();
        request.close();

        //Check the response code of the server -
        Integer replyCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        logMess += "   Reply Code:  " + replyCode.toString();

        responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));

        stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        logMess += "   elapsed Time :  " + elapsedTime + " ms";

        // Of course you do not need to do a time measurement, but it might be interesting 
        Log.d(TAG, "makeHttpRequest --- " + logMess);
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        responseStreamReader.close();

        result = stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "makeHttpRequest --- " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "makeHttpRequest --- " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now just call the method `makeHttpRequest()` from within an `AsyncTask` or background thread like this:

```
Map<String, String> paramList = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
paramList.put("quest", params[0]);
String requestResult = makeHttpRequest(paramList);
```

.

**Note: the method `makeHttpRequest()` must be called from an `AsyncTask` or background thread, otherwise you will get an error!**

.

**Also note that your "stringUrl"  should be pointing to some script like PHP!**